# Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions$Builder" from new Android Project

Tags: android, android-library, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

I created an android library module to implement a logic using Firebase MLKit Vision Library and with sample project works fine locally. But when I try to publish a maven local dependency or export the .aar, I have the following error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions$Builder;
    at com.face.recognition.library.detection.FaceDetectionProcessor.<init>(FaceDetectionProcessor.kt:27)
    at com.face.recognition.library.LegacyLivePreviewActivity.createCameraSource(LegacyLivePreviewActivity.kt:78)
    at com.face.recognition.library.LegacyLivePreviewActivity.onCreate(LegacyLivePreviewActivity.kt:47)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/sample-DiQs8qInpjzgW0pepALP4A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/sample-DiQs8qInpjzgW0pepALP4A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/sample-DiQs8qInpjzgW0pepALP4A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
```

This is my  build.gradle for android library that contains the Firebase MLKit dependency:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    def artifactId = 'com.example'
    def groupId = 'library'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'

    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${app_compat_version}"
    //api(name:'firebase-ml-vision-24.0.3', ext:'aar')
    //api(name:'firebase-ml-vision-face-model-20.0.1', ext:'aar')

    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:${firebase_ml_vision_version}"
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:${firebase_face_model_version}"
   // api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:${junit_version}"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:${android_test_version}"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:${expresso_core_version}"
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            library(MavenPublication) {
                setGroupId groupId
                setArtifactId artifactId
                version android.defaultConfig.versionName

                artifact bundleReleaseAar
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the versions:

```
ext {
     app_compat_version = "1.1.0"
     firebase_core_version = "16.0.9"
     firebase_ml_vision_version = "24.0.3"
     firebase_face_model_version = "20.0.1"
     junit_version = "4.12"
     android_test_version = "1.1.1"
     expresso_core_version = "3.2.0"
     ktx_core_version = "1.1.0" 
}
```

Comment: Show your build.gradle

Comment: did you found any solution?